# Place/address search in QGIS 3.x

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap, qgis-plugins

Are there any plugins for QGIS 3.x versions to search for places or addresses? I know about "OSM place search" in QGIS 2.x, but I can't find a plugin in the repository doing the same job for QGIS 3.x.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since **version 3.20**, the *Nominatim Geocoder* service is now included in QGIS. So no additional plugin is needed anymore.

The service can be accessed using the search bar in the bottom left corner of the QGIS window and the prefix '> ' (note the space).

[image: Nominatim Geocoder demonstration in QGIS]

Answer (score 6):

You need activate "Experimental plugins" and install "**OSM place search**" plugin.

Other alternative is "**Nominatim Locator Filter**"